# Python dataclass inheritance with slots causes AttributeError

Tags: python, inheritance, python-dataclasses, python-3.10, slots

Consider this example with python dataclasses. I am using Python 3.10:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(slots=True)
class A:
    a: int
    
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self.a = a


@dataclass(slots=True)
class B(A):
    b: int
    
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int):
        super().__init__(a)  # Raises Exception below
        self.b = b
```

This raises the following exception:

> TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Note that in the actual production example it is necessary to manually define the `__init__`s. Otherwise, this problem does not appear.

I don't understand why. How do I fix this?

If for `class B` I remove `slots=True` everything works. Also, if I add the slots manually in `class B`, it also works.

Comment: Because using this form of `super` will reference the actual class where it is defined, but using `slots` makes the decorator return *a new distinct class object*, so now the instance (self) will no longer be an instance of the type being passed as the first argume t